# how to read two consecutive commas from .csv file format as unique value in java

Tags: java, csv, stringtokenizer, opencsv

Suppose csv file contains

```
1,112,,ASIF
```

Following code eliminates the null value in between two consecutive commas.
Code provided is more than it is required

```
   String p1=null, p2=null;       
    while ((lineData = Buffreadr.readLine()) != null)
        {
        row = new Vector(); int i=0;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lineData, ",");

               while(st.hasMoreTokens())
               {
                row.addElement(st.nextElement());
                    if (row.get(i).toString().startsWith("\"")==true)
                    {
                        while(row.get(i).toString().endsWith("\"")==false)
                        {
                        p1= row.get(i).toString();
                        p2= st.nextElement().toString();                            
                        row.set(i,p1+", "+p2);
                        }                           
                        String CellValue= row.get(i).toString();
                        CellValue= CellValue.substring(1, CellValue.length() - 1);
                        row.set(i,CellValue);
                        //System.out.println(" Final Cell Value : "+row.get(i).toString());
                    }                       

                                            eror=row.get(i).toString();                     
                        try
                            {
                        eror=eror.replace('\'',' ');
                        eror=eror.replace('['  , ' ');
                        eror=eror.replace(']'  , ' ');
                        //System.out.println("Error "+ eror);
                        row.remove(i);
                        row.insertElementAt(eror, i);
                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                            System.out.println("Error exception "+ eror); 
                            }
                        //}
                i++;
               }
```

how to read two consecutive commas from .csv file format as unique value in java.

Comment: what do you mean by read as unique value in java ?

Comment: by unique i mean separate or existing value that is visible as null cell value when opening csv file in excel

Comment: @Anugoonj: Thank you so much, Information you provide is not doubt helpful. but i have make changes in legacy software ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of doing this by splitting to String array. Changed lines are marked as comments.

```
// Start of your code.
            row = new Vector(); int i=0;
        String[] st = lineData.split(","); // Changed
        for (String s : st) { // Changed
            row.addElement(s); // Changed
            if (row.get(i).toString().startsWith("\"") == true) {
                while (row.get(i).toString().endsWith("\"") == false) {
                    p1 = row.get(i).toString();
                    p2 = s.toString(); // Changed
                    row.set(i, p1 + ", " + p2);
                }
                ...// Rest of Code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the whole line into a string then do `string.split(",")`.

The resulting array should have exactly what you are looking for...

If you need to check for "escaped" commas then you will need some regex for the query instead of a simple ",".

```
while ((lineData = Buffreadr.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] row = line.split(",");
    // Now process the array however you like, each cell in the csv is one entry in the array
```

Comment: that seems other way. Is there any possible way using this code ?

Comment: Probably. I'm not going to use 10 lines of code to do what 2 can do though and in 10 years of Java programming I've never needed StringTokenizer so I can't really help you with it :)

Comment: @RajuS, StringTokenizer ignores empty values by default, you have to use split.

Comment: @vzamanillo: can you explain with any example for string.split(",") ??

Answer (score 0):

The `StringTokenizer` skpis empty tokens. This is their behavious. From the JLS

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Just use `String.split(",")` and you are done.